# Filtering and grouping items in a .NET List<>

Tags: c#, ilist

```
List<MailingList> myGroup = lst.GroupBy(t => new {t.userId, t.userName,t.email,t.reportTypeId})
                             .Select(g => new MailingList
                             {
                               userId = g.Key.userId,
                               Acrynom = g.SelectMany(t => t.Acrynom).ToArray(),
                               userName = g.Key.userName,
                               email = g.Key.email,
                               reportTypeId = g.Key.reportTypeId
                             }).ToList();

foreach (var mailingList in myGroup.Distinct())
{
   StringBuilder AcrynomsList1 = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (var item in mailingList.Acrynom)
   {
      if (Acrynoms.Length > 0)
      {
         Acrynoms.Append(", ");
      }
      AcrynomsList1.Append(item);
   }
}
```

What i want to achieve is filter and group myGroup by reportTypeId. reportTypeId can either be 1 or 2, so i want to have a variable StringBuilder AcrynomsList1 where reportTypeId = 1 and then another variable StringBuilder AcrynomsList2 where reportTypeId = 2.

My current StringBuilder varibale AcrynomsList1 has all reportTypeId 1 & 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
var list =  lst.GroupBy(x => x.reportTypeId)
            .Select(x => new 
                     { 
                         reportTypeId = x.Key, 
                         Acronyms = x.SelectMany(t => t.Acrynom).ToArray()
                     }).ToList();

var acronymList1 = string.Join(", ", list[0].Acronyms);
var acronymList2 = string.Join(", ", list[1].Acronyms);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group it straight into a `string` without using a `StringBuilder`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<MailingList>();
        var grouped = list
            .GroupBy(m => m.ReportTypeID)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                ReportTypeID = g.Key, 
                Items = string.Join(", ", g.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Acronym)).Select(m => m.Acronym))
            });
    }
}

class MailingList
{
    public int ReportTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
}
```

The [GroupBy extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a number of enumerables of `MailingList` for you, which has a `Key` to expose the key you grouped by. The `Distinct` is part of the `GroupBy`, so you don't need it.